# Database replication with composite keys?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

According to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-sbr-rbr.html) on database replication, "All tables replicated using row-based replication must have explicit primary keys."

Is it safe to assume that database replication will work with a composite keys?

Comment: Nope, we have yet to implement database replication.

Answer (score 1):

A primary key can be an composite key.